# In open close principle, what exactly is modification and extension?

Tags: oop, extends, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

Ok, so I know the obvious example of modification, that is when we need to modify an existing behaviour to add a new one. But, when we just need to add code that doesn't change anything but just add new functionality, does this count as modification or extension?

##### Instance:

When we have a `Walking` class representing the behaviour of a walking player and we want to add a `Jumping` class, but need to add methods in the `Walking` class to create the transition between that two behaviour (for declaring how it will go from `Walking` to `Jumping`). 

Does this count as modification? I mean, we wrote code in the `Walking` class, but those code doesn't change anything of the existing behaviour of it (other methods doesn't need to be modified). Or this is an extension(then, by extension, the Open close principle aren't referring to the class `class A extends B`, but any functionality we add in a class)?

Answer (score -1):

If the `Walking` class is public and clients are already using it, then any editing of that class is a modification. Extension would obviously include creating a subclass of `Walking` but also other techniques like object composition, that do not involve editing the class.

Note that the OCP does not prohibit all modifications. The OCP was originally defined by Bertrand Meyer, in [Object-Oriented Software Construction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554). From page 60,

> - If you have control over the original software and can rewrite it so that it will address the needs of several kinds of client at no extra complication, you should do so.

You could interpret this piece of advice from the book as permission to modify the `Walking` class (without breaking clients). On the other hand, the fact that `Jumping` cannot be added without an edit to `Walking` seems to strongly indicate the design is not open for extension.